# PosgresSQL Query return unexpected generated result?

Tags: postgresql

I am currently autogenerating queryies which are supposed to be passed down to a postgres database such that tables, and the data into it can be persisted, and extracted when it is wanted.

I have one column which I generate called entry_name -  which in my case seem to be generated incorrectly for some odd reason?

So in my query - what I expect is that the `entry_name` becomes the same name as the entry in the `work_type` column -  but in my case it seem to be something completly different?  -  some weird combination of an email address, phone number and etc? and I haven't quite understood why this is doing so?

So the entire query is here

```
-- Create table with EntityId
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.Personal 
    (personal_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY);


-- Create table_registration
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.Personal_registration 
(
    personal_id bigint REFERENCES Personal(personal_id),
    row_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    valid tsrange,
    registration tsrange,
    registration_by varchar(255)
);

-- Autogenerated column
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_attribute
               WHERE  attrelid = 'public.Personal_registration'::regclass  -- table name here 
               AND    attname = 'work_type'    -- column name here
               AND    NOT attisdropped
              ) THEN

        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration 
        ADD COLUMN work_type  text NULL;
ELSE
        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration
        ALTER COLUMN  work_type TYPE  text;

END IF;
END
$$;

-- Autogenerated column
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_attribute
               WHERE  attrelid = 'public.Personal_registration'::regclass  -- table name here 
               AND    attname = 'contact_email_address'    -- column name here
               AND    NOT attisdropped
              ) THEN

        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration 
        ADD COLUMN contact_email_address  text NULL;

ELSE
        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration
        ALTER COLUMN  contact_email_address TYPE text;

END IF;
END
$$;

-- Autogenerated column
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_attribute
               WHERE  attrelid = 'public.Personal_registration'::regclass  -- table name here 
               AND    attname = 'contact_mobile_number'    -- column name here
               AND    NOT attisdropped
              ) THEN

        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration 
        ADD COLUMN contact_mobile_number  text NULL;
ELSE
        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration
        ALTER COLUMN contact_mobile_number TYPE text;
END IF;
END
$$;

-- Autogenerated column
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_attribute
               WHERE  attrelid = 'public.Personal_registration'::regclass  -- table name here 
               AND    attname = 'contact_phone_number'    -- column name here
               AND    NOT attisdropped
              ) THEN

        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration 
        ADD COLUMN contact_phone_number  text NULL;

ELSE
        ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration
        ALTER COLUMN contact_phone_number TYPE text;
END IF;
END
$$;

-- Create Generated column
ALTER TABLE public.Personal_registration 
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS entry_name, 
ADD COLUMN entry_name TEXT generated ALWAYS as (CASE WHEN work_type IS NULL THEN NULL 
ELSE work_type END) stored; 


-- Insert an entry
INSERT INTO public.Personal DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING personal_id;


INSERT INTO Personal_registration (personal_id,registration,registration_by,valid,work_type,contact_email_address,contact_mobile_number,contact_phone_number)
                    VALUES (1, 
                            tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'), 
                            'Tester', 
                            tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'),
                            'postman',
                            'dummy@dummy.com',
                            '123456',
                            '654321')
                    RETURNING personal_id,registration,registration_by,valid,work_type,contact_email_address,contact_mobile_number,contact_phone_number, entry_name;
```

And executing this returns this

[image]

This is though not always consistent -  it is sometimes a combination of the mail and number or etc?

I have really no idea of what is going wrong - and have nearly spent 3 days figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into this bug:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAApHDvr7xeMcfGRWQ0rxtagw7CKbjEcjPKfKQAU4KdEcZm6XkQ%40mail.gmail.com#9ac0d8aa3d6ad7e21f4af49a545c8767

You're unlikely to be able to get this working without upgrading PG once a release with the bugfix is out; in the meantime, you should look into doing this with triggers, which have been around in PG forever and are much more mature.

---

The way I established that this was the issue is:

If I change `'postman'` to `'postma'` or `'postmann'`, i get a segfault in the backend when using PG 12.2 on Linux. And, if I have 'postman' as the work_type and then select entry_name from personal_registration, the result is `'dummy@d'`. With `'postma'`, I get the concatenation of a bunch of fields from the RETURNING, and then a different value, truncated to the length of `work_type`, from subsequent selects:

```
testdb=# INSERT INTO Personal_registration (personal_id,registration,registration_by,valid,work_type,contact_email_address,contact_mobile_number,contact_phone_number)
VALUES (1, tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'), 'Tester', tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'),
       'postm', 'dummy@dummy.com', '123456', '654321')
RETURNING entry_name;
                              entry_name                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 mmy@dummy.com\x0F123456\x0F654321ummy@dummy.com\x0F123456\x0F654321u
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
testdb=# INSERT INTO Personal_registration (personal_id,registration,registration_by,valid,work_type,contact_email_address,contact_mobile_number,contact_phone_number)
VALUES (1, tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'), 'Tester', tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'),
       'postman', 'dummy@dummy.com', '123456', '654321')
RETURNING entry_name;
   entry_name    
-----------------
 dummy@dummy.com
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select work_type, contact_email_address, entry_name from personal_registration;
 work_type | contact_email_address | entry_name 
-----------+-----------------------+------------
 postm     | dummy@dummy.com       | mmy@d
 postman   | dummy@dummy.com       | dummy@d
(2 rows)
```

The length-dependent segfault, and the truncation of the value to the length of the value in the generated expression, points to the same issue being the root cause. The exact behavior is likely to be platform-dependent, as per the original bug report.